# Cannot create a private network from Vagrant in VirtualBox after updating it

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have upgraded VirtualBox from 6.1.26-2 to 6.1.28-3 (in Manjaro) and then I was not able to set up a private network with Vagrant.
Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.hostname = "Name"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 2336, id: 'ssh'
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "10.1.45.3", netmask: "255.255.0.0"
end
```

When I did a `vagrant up`, I got:
The IP address configured for the host-only network is not within the
allowed ranges. Please update the address used to be within the allowed
ranges and run the command again.

```
  Address: 10.1.45.3
  Ranges: 192.168.56.0/21

Valid ranges can be modified in the /etc/vbox/networks.conf file. For
more information including valid format see:

  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly
```

I followed the guide from the link and created the file /etc/vbox/networks.conf with:

```
0.0.0.0/0 ::/0
```

And, when I run `vagrant up` again, I got:

```
The IP address configured for the host-only network is not within the
allowed ranges. Please update the address used to be within the allowed
ranges and run the command again.

  Address: 10.1.45.3
  Ranges: 

Valid ranges can be modified in the /etc/vbox/networks.conf file. For
more information including valid format see:

  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly
```

Why does "Ranges" is empty? I tried with other values for ranges but it did not change anything.

I checked the IP for the NAT interface and there was no conflict (10.0.2.15/24).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a missing `*`  at the beginning of the line.
The file *networks.conf* should be:

```
      * 0.0.0.0/0 ::/0
```

Comment: This worked for me as I followed https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly but lost the first character, the '*', when doing the copy and paste. What is the meaning of the syntax for the specification "allow any address".

Answer (score 0):

You could add the network mask and range of addresses using CIDR notation [IP address ranges explained](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-ip-addresses-subnets-and-cidr-notation-for-networking) for the IP address that you want to expose from your guest to the host machine. Add the following to the file `/etc/vbox/networks.conf` and then do `vagrant reload`:

`* 10.1.45.0/24`

This effectively sets apart the first 24 bits, that is the first 3 octets, of the IP address for the network and the rest is the range of address from 0 to 255.